# .htaccess AddType plain/text

Tags: .htaccess, plaintext

I have a page that I dynamically show my Unix scripts in another folder. I added:

AddType text/plain .sh  <-- this is the only thing in .htaccess in the "unix" directory

So I could see the codes, but SOME files are still offered as a download while others go to the correct plain text display.

Here's the site live:

http://snyfarvu.farmingdale.edu/~gerbss/

Unix scripts: guess.sh, add.sh, lock.sh are the ones that are acting up

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Those scripts all work for me using Chrome.  Which browser are you using to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working for me in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac OS X. Did you click those links before adding the .htaccess? If so, your browser may be using the cached response which would be missing the content type header.

Try clearing your browser cache and trying again.